# How to change default search provider and homepage of chorme

Tags: c#, google-chrome

Want to change chrome's default search provider and homepage pragmatically using c#.

There are options like :

1. Edit preferences file of chrome at 
   "C:\users{username}\App Data\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Preferences"

I tried to change homepage by editing this file manually but no luck there.
The preferences file is automatically updated when chrome is relaunched.

2. Using GPO (Group Policy Object) I can change default homepage and chrome settings when I do it manually. For that I have to add Administrative Template for chrome (chrome.adm).

Is this possible in C# to update GPO(Group Policy Object) and add chrome.adm template?

I observed that GPO create Registry Entry for the chrome preference. The registry entry for these preferences is at "HKET_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome"

OR Is there any other way to do the same?

Thank you.